# Ordinary differential equation exercise

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having some trouble solving the following equation:

xy" - y' = 0

y = ?

I tried to use y' = p, therefore y" = p(dp/dy), but after replacing y" and y' in the initial equation, I'm stucked. Please, give me some help.

Thanks!

Comment: this is an example of eulers  equation $$ax^2y'' + bxy' + cy = 0$ the solutions are of the form $x^k$ for the right $k.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let:

$$y = x^m$$

Substitute that into the DE and solve for the $m's$.

**Spoiler**

> $$y(x) = c_1 x^2 + c_2$$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $$xy''-y'=0\implies xy''=y'\implies \frac{d(y')}{y'}=\frac{dx}{x}\implies y'=cx,$$ for some scalar $c$. Hence $y=ax^2+b$, for some scalars $a$ and $b$.